# Is there a Sub procedure equivalent in JS?

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I'm trying to convert some VBscript to JavaScript and was wondering if there is an equivalent of a Sub procedure for JavaScript? Since a Sub procedure is just like a function that doesn't return a value, can I replace a Sub with a function?

Comment: JavaScript only uses `function`. Just ignore the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

> Some functions produce a value, such as power and square, and some
>   don’t, such as makeNoise, which produces only a side effect. A return
>   statement determines the value the function returns. When control
>   comes across such a statement, it immediately jumps out of the current
>   function and gives the returned value to the code that called the
>   function. The return keyword without an expression after it will cause
>   the function to return undefined.

([*](http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html))